# Create Multiple Observables from a Single one - RxSwift

Tags: ios, observable, rx-swift

I have relatively expensive operation so I am willing to perform that operation once and create 2 `Observables` from it.

Here is how it looks:

```
let outputObservable1: Observable<Bool>
let outputObservable2: Observable<Bool>

(outputObservable1, outputObservable2) = inputObservable1.zip(inputObservable2).map { booleanCondition1, booleanCondition2 in
   // different condition combinations create different outputObservables
}
```

I am guessing `map` is not the right operator here as it will only yield one observable. How can I mix and match the conditions and return 2 `Observables` at once?

Comment: Just create the two `Observables`.

Comment: Inside the `map` closure? You are saying just omit what the map returns?

Comment: I'm saying that your question is confusing. My impression is that you have two Observables, and you want to return both Observables. The `zip` operator combines two observables into one so why are you using it? Just return both observables. `return (outputObservable1, outputObservable2)`

Comment: That doesn't make much sense though. The input and output Observable's are completely different. I am mapping input Observables to output ones.

Comment: I think I see what you are asking now... What are the types of the Observables? Provide that in the question and I think I can give you an answer.

Comment: All of them are Booleans! Added that to the question as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my understanding, you just need to use `map`

```
let inputs = Observable.zip(inputObservable1, inputObservable2)
    .share() // you only need this if one of your inputs is making a network request.

let outputObservable1 = inputs
    .map { first, second in 
        return true // or false depending on the values of first & second.
    }
let outputObservable2 = inputs
    .map { first, second in 
        return true // or false depending on the values of first & second.
    }
```

Comment: This looks great! What does the comment 'if one of your inputs is making a network request' mean?

Comment: Most of the time, you don't need the `share()` but if one of the inputObservables cause some sort of side effect when events go through them that might behave differently sometimes, (like a flatMap of a network request) then you will want to put the `share()` in to make sure you don't make multiple network requests.